# Specify options as startup flag or conf file in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

Can I specify all startup options like `-nodebuglogfile` or `-txindex` in bitcoin.conf file as `nodebuglogfile = 0`, `txindex = 0`? Can all startup options/flags without any parameter equivalent to setting them 0 or 1 in bitcoin.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all options can be specified either in bitcoin.conf or as command-line parameters. If an option appears in both then command line takes precedence. Boolean command-line options set to true can omit the value (i.e. both `-txindex` and `-txindex=1` works).